# Rendering a three level data hierarchy into an HTML table with ASP.NET

Tags: linq, nested

Say I had some Airport, Aeroplane, Passenger and Seat classes in C#. Passenger has the id of an Aeroplane and Aeroplane has the id of an Airport. Passenger also has the id of a Seat.

How would I write a linq query to build them into a hierarchy then render them into an HTML table?

I need it to look some like:

```
          1      2      3
Gatwick  
747       July   Kim    Ben
767       Neal   Toby
A380      Becky

Hong Kong
747       Gary   Steve  Gary
MiG-35    Ted

etc..
```

(Seat numbers are along the top)

I've been scratching my head in front of LinqPad for ages but I can only get one level in the hierarchy. I guess I may need to use nested GridViews or maybe write a custom control to render the resulting object but am not sure of the best approch.

Ideally I'd like to get all the data with a single query (a previous programmer has done it  using one query per cell and the page takes a minute to load!)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require 2 LINQ queries:

1. You have to group by seat number (or get seat numbers using .Distinct()). Use this to output the columns;
2. Then group by airport, then airplane, then in each airplane grouping, you have the passengers - you .Join() them with your seats collection.

   ```
   passengers
     .GroupBy(p => p.Aeroplane)
     .GroupBy(p => p.Airport)
     .Join(seats, p=>p.Seat, s=>s, (p,s)=>new { Passenger = p, Seat = seat })
   ```

That will give you an array of passengers and their respective seat in each aeroplane and then in each airport.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok, #1 shouldn't be a problem but I'm a bit unsure about #2.

I can do something this:

    from a in Airpot
    join ap in Aeroplane on a.id == ap.Airport_Id into AirportAeroplane
     select AirportAeroplane

but then how would I join in Passenger?

Thanks (sorry about the formatting btw)